# predicate and logical equivalency question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

i've been given a question

"Are the statements
¬(∀xA(x) → ∀x∀yB(x, y)) and ∀xA(x) ∧ ∃x∃y¬B(x, y)
logically equivalent? If they are equivalent, prove that they are. If not, give an interpretation under which they have different truth values."

I put in an interpretation and the answer was that they ARENT logically equivalent but i'd just like to double check as i'm new to predicates. also, i don't understand "If not, give an interpretation under which they have different truth values." If i worked out the answer through interpretation for A(x) and B(x,y), is that what the question wants?

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are.

The formulae: $\lnot (p \to q)$ and $p \land \lnot q$ are *tautologically equivalent*.

Thus, applying this transformation to $¬(∀xA(x) → ∀x∀yB(x,y))$ we get the equivalent:

> $(∀xA(x) \land \lnot ∀x∀yB(x,y))$.

The final step is to "move inside" the negation sign with the equivalence between $\lnot \forall$ and $\exists \lnot$.

Comment: ok. i understand that. and does the "moving inside" of the negation sign involve going through both statements? could you please explain more what you mean by this? are we trying to get rid of the negation sign?

Comment: @discord1 - I think that you have to review your lecture notes or textbook... for sure the equivalence between $¬∀$  and $∃¬$ will be there.

Comment: ah, so simply ¬∀x∀yB(x,y)) becomes ∃x∃y¬B(x, y)?

Comment: also i had another predicate question that is confusing me as well, Is the statement
(∃xQ(x) ∧ ∃xR(x)) ↔ ∃x(Q(x) ∧ R(x))
logically true? 
so i figured that we can define R(x) and Q(x) as R(x) = 'x is prime' and Q(x) as 'x is even' and test to see if it was true. for (∃xQ(x) ∧ ∃xR(x)) we could interpret as "for some integer x, x is even and for some integer x x is prime" meaning there exists an integer that is prime and an integer that is even? and the second statement we could say "for some integer x, x is prime and even"  meaning there exists a number that is both prime and even. incorrect?

Comment: @discord1 - exactly: firstly $¬∀x∀yB(x,y)$ becomes $∃x¬∀yB(x, y)$ and finally $∃x∃y¬B(x, y)$.